# Configuration of FOSRestBundle with Symfony 4

Tags: fosrestbundle, symfony4

I am trying to implement FOSRestBundle in my Symfony4 project and I am in trouble with the configuration of the bundle.

Based on my documentation, I have to disable view annotation of the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle like this :

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    view: { annotations: false }
```

With this configuration I am supposed to be able to use FOSRest annotation (View).

In Symfony2 I have to write it on the app/config/config.yml file. But in the last version of Symfony this file does not exist anymore. So the question is where should I write this peace of code ?

I am sorry if it a newbie question but I am a bit lost ^^'.
Thanks for reading, I wish you a very good day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file named `sensio_framework_extra.yaml` in the `config/packages` directory and put your content in it.

[image: symfony 4 packages configuration tree view]

You can check your current configuration by launching the following command in your project directory :

```
bin/console debug:config sensio_framework_extra
```